# IE6 (the joys) quirks - sporadic issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Apologies to inflict an IE6 post on everyone - posting in the hope that someone will have had experience of these issues. I don't have a link for now unfortunately, but the first issue is that occasionally images are stretched without keeping aspect ratio - the images have their height and width defined in the  tag, then in the css file their width is set to be a little smaller than that. Sometimes the images load fine, sometimes really badly stretched. Any ideas what is happening here? Fine in all other browsers.

The other issue, which I've not come across before, is that some pages on my site need a refresh of the page for floated elements to align properly. Is there a reason why this could happen in IE6?

Thanks, and apologies again :)

Comment: The images issue sounds like some styling is sneaking in that shouldn't, would need to see the site.  The refresh issue sounds like it would be a FOUC that isn't being fixed.  The  DOM or styling is loaded in a way where the styling isn't being applied as the page is loaded, but everything is cached and available on refresh.

Comment: `max-width:` and `max-height:` does not work in IE6.